# Can I specify a viewport per render target?

Tags: opengl, graphics, viewport, framebuffer

First my problem: I'm trying to render to multiple buffers in an FBO. I set multiple buffers using `glDrawBuffers`, and rendering to them using the appropriate `gl_FragData`. All good and well, but in my situation one of the buffers should be downsampled, by a quarter to be exact (`w/2`, `h/2`).

Of course, I can do this by blitting those specific buffers afterwards or I can simply do the downsampling on the CPU (current solution). But then I read about viewport arrays and found this quote in the [ARB specification](http://www.opengl.org/registry/specs/ARB/viewport_array.txt), which seems to be exactly what I want, without any extra conversions.

> Additionally, when combined with multiple framebuffer attachments, it
>   allows a different viewport rectangle to be selected for each.

Of course, the specification never mentions afterwards how to do this or what they actually mean, `multiple framebuffer attachments` is quite generic. I only noticed I can set a specific viewport as an output of the geometry shader (output `gl_ViewportIndex`). So I could call the geometry twice for each viewport in the array. But as far as I understand, this will simply call the fragment shader with another viewport transformation applied, not one per target buffer. This of course makes not much sense for my usecase, also I can't see how this could ever help to select a viewport per framebuffer attachment

For my situation it does not make much sense to add a geometry shader. And as viewport transform is only applied after the fragment shader, it does make sense to have a viewport per render target, which the previous quote seems to confirm. Is this actually possible, and if so, how would I accomplish this?

Oh, and I've tried the obvious already: resizing the renderbuffer of that target (let's say I use `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1`) to the downsampled version and setting index 1 of the viewport array to the according size. I ended up with a picture of the lower left quadrant of the image, essentially telling me the viewport was unchanged.

Comment: "And as viewport transform is only applied after the fragment shader" The viewport transform is applied before rasterization, not after the fragment shader.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Viewport arrays can only be used with geometry shaders; without them, array index 0 will be used for all rendering.

Remember: the viewport transform happens before rasterization. Thus, if you want to transform a triangle by multiple viewports, you're effectively asking the system to render that triangle *multiple times*. And the only way to do that is with a geometry shader that outputs the primitive multiple times.

Comment: Of course it is applied at rasterization, that was stupid of me :s, I was confused by the fact that `gl_FragCoord` is in normalized coordinates. Have you any idea what they could have meant with that quote then, because I still don't see how you can have a viewport per attachment?

Comment: @KillianDS: Exactly what it says: the geometry shader can send individual triangles to [individual attached layered images](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Framebuffer_Object#Layered_Images), and give each triangle a different viewport. The connection between viewports and image layers is not automatic; it's all done in the GS.

Comment: Aha, using `gl_Layer` then, thank you (my experience with geometry shaders is very little). I think I'll stick to the CPU or blit-solution then, duplicating the fragment calculation is not an immediate option. Thank you.

Comment: "I was confused by the fact that gl_FragCoord is in normalized coordinates." Well, it isn't . It's window space pixel coords.